# student staying in the uk

Tags: visas, uk, turkey, turkish-citizens

**Description**

One turkish person (19 yrs) came to the UK as a short term student. This person is finishing a 1 month course in a week, and wants to know how is it possible to stay in the country for three/four extra months.

According to *[gov.uk/study-visit-visa](https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa)*  it is only possible to stay one month (after this course)  if the whole stay isn't longer than 6 months.

**Question**

this question might be obvious but Id like to clear out all doubt:

1. Is it possible to stay more than one month not as a student but changing the status just to visitor? (as someone just coming to visit england instead of studying)
2. Is there any workaround (like enrolling to a new course) or this person should go back home after 1 month?

Comment: Why can’t this person stay for 6 months? They can study for a course of maximum one month but they can still stay for 6 months I think.

Comment: @HankyPanky the website says that the stay for six months is allowed only when that's the course length...or maybe I'm misreading it. I've linked it to the post

Comment: The way I'm reading the linked page, the student needs to leave within 30 days of the end of the course. Visiting the UK as a tourist requires a different visa.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan is there any mear country you can go just with the turkish passport? thanks for your previous comment...!

Comment: @santimirandarp How about Turkey? That would be the best place to apply for a new visa. London to Istanbul is shorter than a lot of US domestic flights. The closest countries to the UK are the Schengen zone, and I think the student would need a Schengen visa to visit any of them.

Comment: The student should do what they said they’d do when they applied for the short term study visa. That is, complete the course and leave the UK - ideally to return home since that would help future travel plans by demonstrating ties to home country.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to both 1 and 2 seems to be no.

In the *How long you can stay* section there is this statement.

> Your visa will say how long you are allowed to stay in the UK.

It also says this:

> Your visa will say how long you are allowed to stay in the UK.

Presumably your Turkish acquaintance has his visa and has read it and knows when he needs to leave the UK.

In the *what you can and cannot do* section there is this statement:

> You cannot... extend this visa

English officialese is starting to evolve, primarily through its pomposity and circumlocution, into a language other than English but this is clear enough.